# New fetch data is not show on recycler list when pull down to refresh

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement one code where data will come on Scroll and if the data is add on list then we pull down(SwipeRefreshLayout) the new data will come on that list. In my below code the add on data is coming in response but not come in list? I have read many tutorials like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454797/pull-to-refresh-recyclerview-android#) but data is coming on Swipe refresh but not shown on list. Thank you in advance

```
public class UpdatesFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

UserSessionManager session;
private List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
public String user_id;
TextView textView;
FloatingActionButton fab;
public int a=1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_updates, container, false);

    session = new UserSessionManager(getActivity());
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    user_id = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_USER_ID);

    // SwipeRefreshLayout
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,
            android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

    /**
     * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
     * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
     */
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            // Fetching data from server
            getDataFromServer(1);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.updatesRecycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), AddWebPostActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    getDataFromServer(a);

    recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            getDataFromServer(current_page);
        }
    });
}
public void  getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    Log.e("count",String.valueOf(requestCount));
    final String DATA_URL = "https://XYZ.php?username="+user_id + "&page="+requestCount;
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Log.e("URL___________",DATA_URL);
                    Log.e("response___________", String.valueOf(response));
                    parseData(response);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.getCache().clear();
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            superHero.setPost_title(json.getString(Config.TAG_POST_TITLE));
            superHero.setPost_content(json.getString(Config.TAG_POST_CONTENT));
            superHero.setPost_parent(json.getString(Config.TAG_POST_PARENT));
            superHero.setPost_date(json.getString(Config.TAG_POST_DATE));
            superHero.setPost_date_gmt(json.getString(Config.TAG_POST_DATE_GMT));
            superHero.setScheduled_date(json.getString(Config.TAG_SCHEDULED_DATE));
            superHero.setTo_ping(json.getString(Config.TAG_IP_ADDRESS));
            superHero.setVisit_post(json.getString(Config.TAG_VISIT_POST));
            superHero.setUr_id(json.getString(Config.TAG_UR_ID));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when a swipe gesture triggers a refresh.
 */
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    getDataFromServer(1);
  }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

UserSessionManager session;
public String user_id;
public String ur_id;

private Context context;

//String visit;

//List to store all superheroes
List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.web_post, parent, false);
    // Session class instance
    session = new UserSessionManager(context);
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    user_id = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_USER_ID);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    final SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);
    holder.tvPostTitle.setText(superHero.getPost_title());
    holder.tvPostContent.setText(superHero.getPost_content());
    holder.tvPostDateTime1.setText(superHero.getPost_date() +" / " +superHero.getPost_date_gmt());

    final String visit = superHero.getVisit_post();

    holder.tvVisitPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,VisitWebView.class);
            i.putExtra("visitURL",visit);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });  
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Views
    public TextView tvPostTitle,tvPostContent,tvPostDateTime1,tvVisitPost;
    public ImageButton removeButton;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvPostTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostTitle);
        tvPostContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostContent);
        tvPostDateTime1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostDateTime1);
        tvVisitPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVisitPost);
        removeButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> use this method

```
  mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
  @Override
  public void onRefresh() {
```

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
           getDataFromServer(1);

}

> instead of this

```
   mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        // Fetching data from server
        getDataFromServer(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: But ma'am data is coming on response when swipe below and not show on List

Comment: @ParamjeetSingh


   public int getItemCount() {
       return arrData.size();
   }

please debug at this point in the adapter, and check the value for arrData.size()

Comment: @ParamjeetSingh your adapter didn't get the correct size of ArrayList, So please attach your adapter code here, so I can check it

Comment: @ParamjeetSingh - as you have told data is coming, are you sure there is no exception while parsing anf adding items in listSuperHeroes list?

Comment: data is not add on listSuperHeroes list but when I print log below json = array.getJSONObject(i); data is print there

Comment: Can you remove ArrayList initialization from onViewCreated() and directly initialize as global.

Comment: it means the exception is coming while parsing and populating SuperHero model

Comment: @ParamjeetSingh debug parseData method and check the exception

Comment: I have made ArrayList Global

Comment: private List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes =  new ArrayList<>();
Did you intialize like this globally?
and removed from onCreteView()?

I don't think so it will throw an exception

Comment: Ya I did same like this.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq there is no exception

Comment: I print listSuperHeroes.size() below listSuperHeroes.add(superHero); which prints number 11 to 20

Comment: Debug at Adapter constructor, if you are getting the size of ArrayList

Comment: @RiddhiIroid size of list will be 0, as items are not added that point

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq Sir, Items are added on list but new item is not added

Answer (score 0):

**Please call adapter and pass fresh list data after this line**

**listSuperHeroes.add(superHero)** in parseData(response) function ;

```
adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: when you  pull down(SwipeRefreshLayout)  print listSuperHeroes.size() after adding data in list  to ensure weather data is adding in list or not ?

Comment: ya size is same as before add data on that list

Comment: clear list before adding data in list than print list size of course after pulling data ,what hapen this time inform me

Comment: I tried this before posting the question and it shows on one data which is at last pos

Comment: may be it get one new item after pulling

Comment: What does it means

Comment: use this method in your adapter 
pass new list from adapter constructor         ==========================                                                   

public void swapItems(List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes){
    this.listSuperHeroes = listSuperHeroes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();    
}

Comment: and then where should this method to call

Comment: from your adapter constructor