# How to Swipe Refreshing Layout In Recyclerview Like (YouTube)

Tags: javascript, android-studio

How To Refresh **RecyclerView** List Like YouTube By Swiping Refresh layout

**activity_main.xml:-**
This Is My Main Activity java

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ImagesActivity">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/Swipe_Refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />     
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java** 
And This Is My MainActivity.Java+
please tell me the code

```
   public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

        private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

        private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
        private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
        private ValueEventListener mDBListener;

        private List<Upload> mUploads;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.Swipe_Refresh);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                    }
                }
        );

            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

            mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);

            mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

            mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    mUploads.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);
                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Normal click at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onWhatEverClick(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Whatever click at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
            Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
            final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

            StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
            imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
        }
    }
```

**ImageAdapter.java**
This Is My Image Adapter

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
            MenuItem doWhatever = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Do whatever");
            MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");

            doWhatever.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case 1:
                            mListener.onWhatEverClick(position);
                            return true;
                        case 2:
                            mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);

        void onWhatEverClick(int position);

        void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}

**Upload.java**
```

**This My Upload Class**
        package com.codinginflow.firebaseuploadexample;

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mKey;

    public Upload() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }

        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setKey(String key) {
        mKey = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Guys Can You Please Update The Answer As Soon As Possible

Comment: I Need Code Please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to View Swipe Refreshing Layout In Recyclerview Like (YouTube) .Here Is My Code Am Already Add Swipe Refresh Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520521/how-to-view-swipe-refreshing-layout-in-recyclerview-like-youtube-here-is-my-c)

Comment: please Update Answer To This question Sir please

Comment: I am not and android developer so I am not familiar with this issue. BUT still, you cannot open new question same as the last just because you were not getting any response. Consider edit your question. Did you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454797/pull-to-refresh-recyclerview-android?

Comment: But Please Update Code To My Question

Comment: PLease Answer The Code Of This Question As Soon As Possible

Comment: I Need Code Please